# Is this the definition of over-fitting?

Tags: machine-learning, overfitting

Overfitting is when we have a model which has memorized the training data and does not perform well in real-world cases.

Okay, say that I had some training points which look like this:

[image]

What if the red curve was the actual 'real-world' relationship. And I found this exact model through a learning algorithm based on those training observations.

Has my model overfit by definition despite it being the 'real-world' relationship? I am assuming yes, but I just want to make sure.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I think it may be useful to rephrase the definition of overfitting to something like:

> A model that does not generalize well to real-world cases *although* it fits the training data well.

As for your example:

- If the real world looks like the red line there is by definition no overfitting.
- But at the same time, if the black dots are all real-world test data you have, you probably still cannot prove this: in real-world situations, 10 cases are just not enough to prove that a function of the shown complexity was successfully fit.
- To give you an idea about one real-world field: in analytical chemistry, a series of 10 concentration steps covering your desired range of analyte concentrations is usually required to show that your method yields *linear* response.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at your error on the training and on the validation data. If the validation error increases while the training error decreases then a situation of overfitting may have occurred. The best predictive and fitted model would be where the validation error has its global minimum.

Comment: Agreed. The critical point is that overfitting occurs when performance on your training set gets better *at a cost of the model generalizing less well*. While in this case it certainly looks like what we see when a model overfits, if the real world curve really does match the one your training produced, then your model generalizes as well as can be.

Comment: What if training error is 0 and validation error is 0, have I still overfit by definition?

Comment: I don't think so, no. Your validation error has not got worse. Take a look at the initial definition you give: "Overfitting is when we have a model which has memorized the training data *AND* does not perform well in real-world cases". The 'and' there is crucial. Yes, your model has memorized the training set - but it performs excellently on real world cases. So it has not overfit.

Comment: So I have a model that has a lot of variance but does not overfit. Am I correct? Usually, variance and overfitting go together (as they say).